# Is it possible with Doxygen to have the detailed descriptions inline instead of in a separate section of the page?

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I'm trying to use Doxygen for documenting some API written in C#, but I find the flow of the information in the generated pages needlessly fragmented. All the methods with brief descriptions are listed first, and then they are listed again underneath with more detailed descriptions.

What's the point of this when the details could be shown inline with foldouts? Doxygen already use foldouts extensively in the sidebar when GENERATE_TREEVIEW is set to YES, so clearly supports the concept of content revealed and hidden via foldouts.

This image illustrates what I'm looking for:

[image]

I've looked quite a bit for an answer for whether this can be achieved with special settings or custom CSS without outright modifying the Doxygen source, but haven't been able to find out anything about it.

Another way to describe the issue: Doxygen generates class pages like this:

- Brief class description.
- Brief member A description
- Brief member B description
- Brief member C description
- Detailed class description.
- Detailed member A description
- Detailed member B description
- Detailed member C description

Whereas I want

- Brief class description.
- Detailed class description (foldout).
- Brief member A description
- Detailed member A description (foldout).
- Brief member B description
- Detailed member B description (foldout).
- Brief member C description
- Detailed member C description (foldout).

The detailed ones would of course not need to repeat any info already in the brief descriptions here, as the brief description of each member would be immediately above the detailed one.

I have investigated the configuration options and the DoxygenLayout.xml file, and none of those provide mechanisms for this. For example, the xml file contains an entry like this:

```
<memberdecl>
    ...
    <publicmethods title=""/>
```

But this generates ALL the public methods brief descriptions at once, without any possibility of inserting extra info for each of them.

Comment: GENERATE_TREEVIEW and the righthand side of the output are completely different (more or less javascript versus HTML). When I understand it you don*t want the brief description section and the parts in the detailed description which should show by default the brief description but and a collapsed detailed section. Is this correct? The first part can be accomplished by means of the e.g. https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html though one has to keep in mind that some entities don't have a brief description.

Comment: For the detailed I don't see a solution, maybe something is possible by means the css files and using `<div class="memdoc">` and of this the first `<p>´ and the other information in the section.

Comment: @albert I don't fully understand your comments, but I've inserted extra details in my questions about what it is I mean. The page about customization does not seem to cover anything like this, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The things you described are what I understood. What doxygen can do is to repeat the brief description as first paragraph in the detailed description, this paragraph might, maybe, be used as as a sort of title (like the ´<summary>` inside the HTML `<details>´ tag. For this I don't yet see a solution (only by making some, rather big, changes to the doxygen code. Thinking about it...). Another approach might be to modify the DoxygenLaout.xml (generated by `doxygen -l`) by placing the `<detaileddescription title=""/>`of the `<class>`directly after the ``<briefdescription`.

Comment: Probably best to create an issue in the doxygen issue tracker on GitHub (here it is easier to add attachments and images,